# DAX column creation based on multiple conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

| TR Type | TR Code | BK | TR Txt |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CD | 456 | 1.91E+13 | ST |  |
| CD | 123 | 41 | CDC |  |
| CD | 123 | 41 | CDC |  |
| CD | 123 | 1 | CDC |  |
| CD | 123 | 41 | CDC |  |
| DT | 123 | 1 | CDC |  |
| DT | 123 | 41 | CDC |  |
| DT | 123 | 41 | CDC |  |
| DT | 123 | 41 | CDC |  |

I'm trying to create a column which contains multiple conditions like so and here is my code below.

● BD: TR Type = CD, TR Code = 123, BK = 41, TR Text Does Not Contain "DCD"

● MD: TR Type = CD, TR Code = 123, BK  = 41, TR Text Contains "DCD"

● LD: TR Type = CD, TR Code = 125, BK = 54

● BMDS: TR Type = CD, TR Code = 123, BK has more than 6 digits (excl. leading zeros)

```
Column = 
  SWITCH(TRUE(),
    [TR Type] = "CRD" && [TR Code] = 123 && [BK Trx #] = 41 && NOT(CONTAINSSTRING([TR Text], "CDC")), "BD",
    [TR Type] = "CRD" && [TR Code] = 123 && [BK Trx #] = 41 && CONTAINSSTRING([TR Text], "CDC"), "MD",
    [TR Type] = "CRD" && [TR Code] = 123 && [BK Trx #] = 54, "ST"
  )
```

Problem:
Error DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type Int

Comment: from the looks of it, i suspect that you have Text in the column `[BK Trx #]`, you can check that

Comment: TR Type = Text
TR Code = General
BK Trx = General (has blanks no text)
TR Text = Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory.  There is some element that is or at least Power BI sees as text being compared to an int.  The solution is to ensure all of the comparisons are of the same data type.
I would

- Go to the transform data section
- In the power query editor, select the table and columns to modify
- Click on the column headers and change them to Text or Whole Number as required
- Close and apply.

This will also throw an error if there is something power query can't do (e.g. convert a text to an int.

You can also use the Value function to convert the text to numbers, use quotes to treat numbers as text, etc.

Last ditch option I wouldn't do but should point out as an option is you can quote all of the items so that they're all working from text values.  like this:

```
Column = 
  SWITCH(TRUE(),
    [TR Type] = "CD" && [TR Code] = "123" && [BK] = "41" && NOT(CONTAINSSTRING([TR Txt], "CDC")), "BD",
    [TR Type] = "CD" && [TR Code] = "123" && [BK] = "41" && CONTAINSSTRING([TR Txt], "CDC"), "MD",
    [TR Type] = "CD" && [TR Code] = "125" && [BK] = "54", "LD",
    [TR Type] = "CD" && [TR Code] = "123" && LEN([BK]) > 6, "BMDS",
    BLANK()
  )
```